# Ant / Ivy checking existing dependencies before contacting remote repository

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I want ant/ivy to check first if the dependencies are already downloaded, and only use ivy to resolve missing dependencies. In other words, I don't want ivy to contact remote repositories if all the dependencies have already been resolved and downloaded.

How do I configure this behavior?

This would be useful for re-building a project without an internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify [chain of resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/resolver/chain.html). In this way you put your local repository first and the remote repositories at the end.